# A TINY PUZZLE - Where is Fiabangu?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

> *The Valley - "Bakudilich" iș in Ăurigasu, Vaprist in Adohalu and Aquitom in Skabuja, so.. Fiabangu is in ?*

**Replace the question mark with correct word to complete the sentence.**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fiabangu is in

> **Gapore.**

This is because

> The whole text is a disguised list of capitals of states/territories.
>
>  Here is the same text with slashes placed appropriately: The Valley / Baku/dili/ch is in Au/riga/su Va/prist in A/doha/lu and A/quito/m in Sk/abuja/so Fia/bangu i/s in... The words separated by slashes are the capitals of Anguilla, Azerbaijan, Timor-Leste, Moldova, Latvia, Fiji, Kosovo, Qatar, Angola, Ecuador, Belarus, Nigeria, Bulgaria, and the Central African Republic, respectively.
>
>  However, there are still three letters remaining at the end, which are "sin". Because of the theme we assume that we are looking for another state capital starting with "sin". And there is only one such capital: the capital of Singapore, which is itself. (This also explains the title, since Singapore is tiny.) Since "sin" is already there, the missing "place" is thus "Gapore".

Comment: Thatsrigh Tyoudi Dagre Atjob :)

Comment: Ididno Tbelie Vetha Titissp Okenth Atway!

Comment: Andalw Aysple Asupv Otem Ycommen Tsands Ayyes!